# Two dimensional dynamic array via functions with random numbers

Tags: c++, c++17

I've starting programming in c++ a month ago and i faced a serious and hidden problem(or error). The errors occured in 12 and 22 line of the code in a nested loop, the "j" variable in arr[i][j], and i absolutely dont know how to solve.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void FillArray(int arr[], int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;   // here
        }
    }
}
void PrintArray(int arr[], int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';   // and here
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void  main() 
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int rows, cols;
    cout << "Enter rows count: " << endl;
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Enter colums count: " << endl;
    cin >> cols;
    int **arr = new int* [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[cols];
    }

    FillArray(*arr, rows, cols);

    PrintArray(*arr, rows, cols);

    


        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete arr;
}
```

I have tried to use and delete pointers and references for variables and arrays, but they are not working.

Comment: `int arr[]` is not the same as `int **`, is it?

Comment: Really? " int** " i have used for to create dynamic array

Comment: `void main()` isn't required to work in C++. Perhaps some compilers support it as an extension but I suggest using the standard `int main()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you designed functions that require a one-dimensional array as the first parameter, but you tried to access a two-dimensional array.

```
void FillArray(int arr[], int rows, int cols) // int arr[] is one-dimensional
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;   // arr[i][j] is two-dimensional
        }
    }
}
```

You have two options:

1. Modify the functions to accept two-dimensional arrays:

   ```
   void FillArray( int arr[][7] , int rows , int cols )
   ```

In this case, however, you must necessarily specify the value of the second dimension (7 is just an example).

2. Modify the functions to accept a pointer to a int pointer:

   ```
   void FillArray( int** arr , int rows , int cols )
   ```

Since the number of columns is determined at runtime, I exclude the first option: the size of arrays, whether one-dimensional or multi-dimensional, must be known at compile time.

Another note: in the main, you correctly released the memory allocated by the pointers contained in the memory allocated by arr.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    delete[] arr[i];
}
```

But then you also have to release the memory allocated by `arr`. So:

```
delete[] arr;
```

Here the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void FillArray(int** arr, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}

void PrintArray(int** arr, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int rows, cols;
    cout << "Enter rows count: " << endl;
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Enter colums count: " << endl;
    cin >> cols;
    int** arr = new int* [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[cols];
    }

    FillArray(arr, rows, cols);

    PrintArray(arr, rows, cols);


    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
}
```